# Reading lines from file and assigning content to variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a file with many lines. Each line has the same length.

The first three lines are:

```
0 MSG_201901010100.nc   [98.22227, 0.00014308207]  [3948.8948, 0.0057524233]
1 MSG_201901010200.nc  [197.27554, 0.00028737469]     [9986.71, 0.014547813]
2 MSG_201901010300.nc  [218.46107, 0.00031823604]   [12044.043, 0.017544765]
```

How can I read in the file and assign the content to lists, arrays or a Dataframe?

As lists I would like to have:

```
a = [0,1,2]
b = [R10CH20P_MSG_201901010100.nc, R10CH20P_MSG_201901010200.nc, R10CH20P_MSG_201901010300.nc]
c1 = [98.22227, 197.27554, 218.46107]
c2 = [0.00014308207, 0.00028737469,0.00031823604]
d1 = [3948.8948, 9986.71, 12044.043]
d2 = [0.0057524233, 0.014547813, 0.017544765]
```

I tried to read the file with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\s+', names=['a', 'b', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2' ])
```

But this produces wrong assignments:

```
print(df)

   a                    b           c1              c2           d1             d2
0  0  MSG_201901010100.nc   [98.22227,  0.00014308207]  [3948.8948,  0.0057524233]
1  1  MSG_201901010200.nc  [197.27554,  0.00028737469]    [9986.71,   0.014547813]
2  2  MSG_201901010300.nc  [218.46107,  0.00031823604]  [12044.043,   0.017544765]
```

For example `print(df['c1']`) gives:

```
0     [98.22227,
1    [197.27554,
2    [218.46107,
Name: c1, dtype: object
```

and

`print(df['c1'].values)` shows:

```
['[98.22227,' '[197.27554,' '[218.46107,']
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. If you [strip off](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) the brackets and commas, you have essentially the output you're looking for, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your use case,

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    data = []
    for s in lines:
        s = s.replace('[', '')
        s = s.replace(']', '')
        s = s.replace(',', '')
        data.append(s.split())
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1', 'd2'])
```

And finally,

```
a = df['a'].tolist()
b= df['b'].tolist()
```